# Is there any API to check if the user is using Banner mode or Full Screen mode in iOS14?

Tags: ios, swift, call, ios14

Apple introduced banner mode for incoming calls but is there any API to check is the user using Banner mode or full-screen mode in the iOS 14?

Comment: I don't think you can detect that. In fact, you can't really detect what causes the app to resign active. I checked now, but I might be wrong and there is a way.